# Entity key and data properties not defined when retrieving from local datastore

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

I'm trying to follow along the Googles doc here is the problem I'm facing. According to the doc [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/google-cloud/0.43.0/datastore) when i retrieve an entity like this

```
var key = datastore.key(['Company', 'Google']);

datastore.get(key, function(err, entity) {
    // entity.data = The record.
    // entity.key = The key.
});
```

I should get an entity object with the key and data properties. That's not what I'm getting. Here's my read function

```
function read(kind, id, cb) {
    var key = datastore.key([kind, parseInt(id, 10)]);
    datastore.get(key, (err, entity) => {
    if(err) {
        return cb(err);
    }

    if(!entity) {
        return cb({
            code: 404,
            message: 'Not found'
        });
    }
    cb(null, entity.data);
});
}
```

Neither data or key are defined. Instead, the retrieved entity looks like this

```
{
  "age": 23,
  "name": "Hello World"
}
```

Which obviously is just the data. What am i doing wrong? I'm working on the gcloud datastore emulator

Here are my dependencies if it's relevant

```
"dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "google-cloud": "^0.43.0",
    "yargs": "^5.0.0"
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since @google-cloud/datastore v0.5.0 the key is accesible from a Symbol.

```
var datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore')();

var key = datastore.key(['Company', 'Google']);

datastore.get(key, function(err, entity) {
    var key = entity[datastore.KEY];
});
```

Of course you could always use gstore-node (disclaimer: I'm the owner of that library) and then you would just access it by entity.entityKey.

Comment: Thank you, this works. But i must say i really am frustrated by this. They couldn't update their docs?

Comment: Yeah I discovered it because it broke gstore-node and had to look into their commit.

Comment: Actually they updated the query
    query.run(function(err, entities) {
            var keys = entities.map(function(entity) {
            return entity[datastore.KEY];
        });
    });